# Azure IOT device update tutorial files not working on Raspberry Pi 3b/3b+ shared in link: https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/releases

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-iot-hub, ota

I have been trying to try OTA update on Raspberry Pi mentioned via their website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-agent-provisioning

However, whenever we flash the SD card and boot up for the first time the device is getting stuck as in the image [the raspberry Pi boot stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssxZH.jpg)

Could anyone please guide on what can be done so as to fix issue and go ahead?

Comment: Are you sure this image is for a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes. It's the same from Microsoft page.

Comment: As far as I know, their image _only_ runs on a Raspberry Pi 3, not on a Pi 4. Yours appears to be a Pi4.

Comment: I used RasPi 3 / 3b+ only

Comment: I never tried this before, because I don't have an Pi3's. So I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: You followed this: [Flash SD card with image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/iot-hub-device-update/device-update-raspberry-pi#flash-sd-card-with-image) and then used the base image adu-base-image-raspberrypi3-0.7.5198.1.wic.gz ?

Comment: I did. I also used the other flash tools too. Every try it gets stuck at same place.

Comment: There are other releases you could test. Can you open an issue in the github repo? Product Team will check your logs: https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/issues

Comment: @Praful Kabadi any luck getting this issue sorted out? Would help if you can share error messages you may see before it gots stuck.

Comment: We have reached out to Microsoft team directly and are checking the same with them.